# Reading Data from a Socket with WSAAsyncSelect

Tags: sockets, winapi

Is it ok to invoke `WSAAsyncSelect` in the `WM_CREATE` message of a Window Process (`WinProc`), and then perform all `recv` actions inside the same `WinProc` (e.g. to `recv` and populate a control with the received byte data) under `WM_SOCKET`?

For example, I know that performing long tasks inside the `WinProc` can cause the window to be unresponsive (since it cannot handle other messages until this message is completed), but I've seen no examples that treat this `recv` I/O with a thread or event object.  Is it completely unnecessary?

Here's the example case in the `WinProc` I've seen on the net, and also in Petzold the `recv` is handled in a similar fashion:

```
    case WM_SOCKET:
    {
        if(WSAGETSELECTERROR(lParam))
        {   
            MessageBox(hWnd,
                "Connection to server failed",
                "Error",
                MB_OK|MB_ICONERROR);
            SendMessage(hWnd,WM_DESTROY,NULL,NULL);
            break;
        }
        switch(WSAGETSELECTEVENT(lParam))
        {
            case FD_READ:
            {
                char szIncoming[1024];
                ZeroMemory(szIncoming,sizeof(szIncoming));

                int inDataLength=recv(Socket,
                    (char*)szIncoming,
                    sizeof(szIncoming)/sizeof(szIncoming[0]),
                    0);

                strncat(szHistory,szIncoming,inDataLength);
                strcat(szHistory,"\r\n");

                SendMessage(hEditIn,
                    WM_SETTEXT,
                    sizeof(szIncoming)-1,
                    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&szHistory));
            }
            break;

            case FD_CLOSE:
            {
                MessageBox(hWnd,
                    "Server closed connection",
                    "Connection closed!",
                    MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK);
                closesocket(Socket);
                SendMessage(hWnd,WM_DESTROY,NULL,NULL);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the I/O blocks, your window will freeze up - it's as simple as that really.

Comment: In a non-blocking mode, it does not matter if you try to read more than is available, it will always return immediately and never block. Either nothing is available yet (`WSAEWOULDBLOCK` error) or it reads whatever is available up to your specified buffer size at most.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is perfectly acceptable. Though typically you would wait until `CreateWindow/Ex()` exits before then calling `WSAAsyncSelect()`. But either way works fine.  Just be sure to handle the case where `recv()` fails, or returns fewer bytes than you asked for.